# Redux Dev Tools doesn't show state change, action.payload is { }

Tags: reactjs, redux, rxjs, redux-observable, typesafe-actions

I am trying to figure out why Redux-Devtools does not show state change because it shows that `action={
  type: 'GET_LOCATION_SUCCESS',
  payload: {}
}`, while `debugger` and `console.log()` shows that `action.payload` is n.
I am using

- `redux-observable`
- `rxjs`
- `typesafe-actions`

This is my action creator:

```
import { createAsyncAction } from 'typesafe-actions';
import { GET_LOCATION_BEGIN, GET_LOCATION_FAILURE, GET_LOCATION_SUCCESS } from './constants';

export const getMyLocation = createAsyncAction(
    GET_LOCATION_BEGIN,
    GET_LOCATION_SUCCESS,
    GET_LOCATION_FAILURE
)<undefined, Position, string>();
```

This is my reducer:

```
import { RootAction } from 'MyTypes';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { getType } from 'typesafe-actions';

import {getMyLocation} from '../actions/locationActions';

export type locationState = {
    position: Position;
    error: boolean;
};

export const locationReducer = combineReducers<locationState, RootAction>({
    position: (state = {} as Position, action) => {
        switch(action.type){
            case getType(getMyLocation.success):
                return action.payload;
            default:
                return state;
        }
    },
    error: (state = false, action) => {
        switch(action.type){
            case getType(getMyLocation.failure):
                return true;
            default:
                return state;
        }
    }
})
```

And this is my epic: [EDIT v.1]

```
   export const getMyLocationEpic: Epic<RootAction, RootAction, RootState, Services> = (action$, state$, {geoLocation}) => 
  action$.pipe(
    filter(isActionOf(getMyLocation.request)),
    switchMap( () => geoLocation.getGeoLocation(options).pipe(
        take(1),
        mergeMap( (data : Position) => of(
          // Dispatch action with my location data and then dispatch action to request weather from API. It runs fetchWeatherEpic
          getMyLocation.success(data),
          fetchWeather.request(data)
          )
        ),
        catchError(err => of(getMyLocation.failure(err)))
      )
    )
  );
```

I am wondering what might be the reason of not showing state update, it works as it should in `console.log()` but it doesn't work in devtools.

Comment: could you send reducer an effects of action `GET_LOCATION_SUCCESS`

Comment: Did you mean that, what I have updated in implementation of Epic? `(data : Position) => of(
          getMyLocation.success(data)`

Comment: Epic are dispatching other actions based on already dispatched action. Recuders are responsive for updating state. If you don't have reducer for `GET_LOCATION_SUCCESS` state will be the same after dispatched this action.

Comment: `GET_LOCATION_SUCCESS` is `getMyLocation.success` it is async action from `typesafe-actions` library.

Comment: i see. could add `console.log(state, action.payload)` just after `case getType(getMyLocation.success):` and send output